# Can I subdivide vertices in a single direction?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Is it possible to almost duplicate or split vertices but keep them part of the edge that that they're on? Subdividing basically works, but if I try to do multiple edges at once, it does it in all locations. I can do it by subdividing and then dissolving the leftover vertices or by subdividing alone and then connecting the vertices, but is there an easier way?

The closest thing that I've found is "Loop Cut and Slide", but that just creates new vertices only connected to the ones I did it from instead of inserting new vertices in the edges.

For example, if I have this mesh:
[image: A basic grid on a rectangle.]

I would like to do this:
[image: The same grid with two new vertices parallel to previous vertices and on the same edges.]

If I select the vertices on the other side and subdivide it, it gives me this though:
[image: The same grid with vertices on the perpendicular edges too.]

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: What about extrude (`E`) or rip (`V`)?

Comment: @gandalf3: Extrude is basically like Loop Cut except it doesn't slide it. Rip is basically like that too. I don't want to create new stuff really, I just want to divide the vertices along the existing edge. I can do it by carefully subdividing, but that's really slow.

Comment: So you basically want something faster than to select two verts connected by an edge, subdivide, vertex slide? How about the knife tool? Requires more than a click too, but no need to select the edge verts first.

Comment: @CoDEmanX I guess so. It would be nice if it would work for multiple vertices at once, but that's basically it.

Comment: @Ullallulloo It does for me, try using `E` to start a new cut.

Comment: @gandalf3: No, it's definitely just creating new entirely new edges instead of just adding new vertices to the current ones.

Comment: @Ullallulloo I mean in the knife tool.

Comment: @gandalf3: Oh, that seems basically right. It isn't lined up with the current vertices, but it does basically what I was looking for.

Comment: As long as you don't cross a face with a single cut, knife tool won't add new edges, just verts. It requires you to draw a line crossing an edge however, for your special purpose, it would be nicer to have a tool like the knife to subdivide an edge at click location instantly.

Comment: @Ullallulloo If I didn't misunderstand, you want the new vertices (two more per edge) share the same position with the original ones?

Comment: @LeonCheung: I would prefer them to, I guess, but I don't really need one on both sides of the edge. Subdividing is basically what I want, but when I try to do it for multiple vertices it divides it everywhere. I tried to edit the question to better reflect what I mean.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is about (the title mentions vertices). It looks like the title should be "How to split a quad into two quads?". Please consider adjusting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> > **Edge**. Then subdivide as you want.

Comparison:

[image]

Comment: @Ullallulloo: Select the new center edge and hit `GG` to edge-slide, to achieve what you showed in your screenshot

Comment: it took me some time to get that multiselect with ctrl selects the edge in between too, while with shift it do not (the opposite behavior then any other application)

Comment: @OhadCohen Is it possible that you changed the keymap preset, say, to 3ds Max?

Comment: I changed it to 3ds max and now it works normally. thanks