# Subdivide in only one direction?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, geometry

Say I have the top mesh in the image. If I subdivide it, I'll have the second mesh in the image. But what I want is the third. It has vertical subdivisions, but not horizontal. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3259/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6415/599

Answer (score 22):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> into Edit mode, if you're not already there.
Then either
1. Select **only** the horizontal edges, then subdivide.
or
2. For each of the three sections, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and hover the mouse near a horizontal edge, then <kbd>LMB</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> followed by <kbd>RMB</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>.